# How to draw concentric circles like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw concentric circles like this?

[image]

Comment: Try with _Asymptote_: `size(300);unitsize(1cm);defaultpen(linewidth(.8bp));draw(Label("$A$",position=Relative(.08)),circle(0,1.5));draw(Label("$B$",align=LeftSide,position=Relative(.08)),circle(0,.8));`. Try with _PSTricks_: 
`\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
 \pscircle(0,0){1.5cm}
 \pscircle(0,0){.8cm}
 \uput[45](1.5cm;10){$A$}
 \uput[-165](.8cm;10){$B$}
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @justonly, please convert your comment to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With use of node with circle shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \r/\c in {1/B, 2/A} 
      {
        \node[circle, draw, minimum size=2*\r cm,label=right:\c] {};
      }
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks nice.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

This is a straightforward use of [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \c/\r in {A/2, B/1} {
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=\r];
        \node[right] at (\r+0.1,0) {$\c$};
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

With `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(3,2){O}
\tkzDrawCircles[R](O,2cm O,3cm)
\tkzLabelCircle[R,above right](O,2cm)(60){$B$} 
\tkzLabelCircle[R,above right](O,3cm)(60){$A$}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! @Alain Matthes